# iPhone FBConnectDialog box disappears

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

So I've been trying to integrate FB with my iPhone application with FB connect.  However, after using the tutorial (http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/), it seems when the FBDialog box is called, it pops onto the screen for a few seconds and then disappears.  I'm not sure what is going, becuase IT WORKS in the Simulator perfectly. I have an iPhone 4 device.  Here is my code below:

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:@"MYAPIKEY" secret:@"MYSECRET"                  delegate:self] retain];

  FBLoginButton *button = [[[FBLoginButton alloc] init] autorelease];

  [button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)];

  [self.view addSubview:button];

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm sorry for being a noob.  Turns out my three hour struggle to figure this out was a complete waste.  The problem -- my iPhone wasn't connected to Wifi/cell network.

Comment: Not a problem,user487588. That is how you will learn from your mistakes. Keep this in mind next time though. :)